# Получение айди telegram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telethon

Я пытаюсь сделать так чтобы мой бот по нику мог определить айди. Создал приложение получил токен и хеш дальше начались проблеммы:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.users import GetFullUserRequest
def get_user(username):
   API_ID = айди
   API_HASH = "хеш"
   with TelegramClient('имя приложения', API_ID, API_HASH) as client:
       user = client(GetFullUserRequest(username))
   return user
id = get_user("юзер нейм корторый ищу")
```

При запуске данного кода и использовании токена моего бота, получаю ошибку

```
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'UserMethods.__call__' was never awaited
```

Помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient

def get_user(username):
    API_ID = id
    API_HASH = "hash"
    client = TelegramClient('program name', API_ID, API_HASH)
    client.connect()
    user = client.get_peer_id(username)
    return user


ids = get_user("@username")
print(ids)
```

Если нужно будет сделать приложение асинхронным, чтобы оно быстро работало, почитай про await
А ещё есть [документация](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/) по telethon

Там говорится про использование await в самом начале

Answer (score 2):

Telethon является асинхронной библиотекой, поэтому ругается на отсутствие async.
Попробуйте так:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.users import GetFullUserRequest

API_ID = айди
API_HASH = "хеш"
client = TelegramClient('имя приложения', API_ID, API_HASH)

async def get_user(username: str):
    return client.GetFullUserRequest(username)

async def main():
    id_ = await get_user("юзер нейм корторый ищу")
    print(id_)

with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Надеюсь, что мой ответ Вам поможет.

Comment: RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback (